# How to apply CSS to :last-child button

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

See picture example below, I'd like to know how it is possible to make the last button in a row of divs a different color. Can it be achieved using :last-child using CSS within the DIVs?

I'd like to make the last button green like the design I have below:

Thanks!

[image: Picture example of how i'd like the button to look]

HTML:

```
<div class="span3">
    <h3 class="icon_office">Daily office cleaning</h3>
    <p>Office, meeting rooms, communal areas, washrooms and hygiene areas.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#>Learn More</a>
</div>

<div class="span3">
     <h3 class="icon_retail">Retail cleaning</h3>
     <p>The cleaning and maintenance of public circulation areas, shopping centres, retail complexes etc.</p>
     <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn More</a>
</div>

<div class="span3">
     <h3 class="icon_edu">Educational cleaning</h3>
     <p>The general cleaning of all aspects of public sector establishments, schools and colleges.</p>
     <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn More</a>
</div>

<div class="span3">
    <h3 class="icon_special">Specialist cleaning</h3>
    <p>We also provide specialist cleaning and support services.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `:last-child`:

```
.services .span3:last-child .btn {
   background : green;
}
```

Using adjacent sibling selector:

```
.services .icon_special + p + .btn {
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should apply `:last-child` to the last div,containing this button (link styled as button) :

```
.services div.span3:last-child > a {
   background : green;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xJ66M/)

Comment: This will do what you need, just be sure to scope it to .services so you dont cause any conflicts with other sections using .span3.

Answer (score 1):

Or this could be done using some jQuery:

```
$('.span3').last().addClass('green')
```

Answer (score 0):

`.span3:last-child .btn{}` does the trick